# Is this problem in P or NP-Complete?

Tags: graph-theory, np-complete

I need to determine if the following problem is in P or NP-Complete:

$\mathrm{2-IS} = \{\left< G, k\right > | G \text{ is a graph which every node in it has a degree 2 AND there is an independent set of size $k$ in $G$}\}$

My intuition says it's in NP-Complete but I can't find another NP-Complete problem to reduce it to... any help?

Comment: Hint: Think about how graphs where every node has degree 2 look like.

Comment: If every node has degree 2, then it must be the union of cycles of length $k_i$. There is an independent set of size $\sum\lfloor \frac{k_i + 1}{2} \rfloor$.

Comment: @Calvin: Of course $\left\lfloor\frac{k_i+1}2\right\rfloor=\left\lceil\frac{k_i}2\right\rceil$.

Comment: @CalvinLin what is ki? please further explain

Comment: and @sdcvvc can you please be more specific? We are talking about reducing from a known problem in NP-complete to 2-IS?

Comment: The problem is not NP-complete (well, unless P=NP); Calvin and sdcvvc were providing hints for finding a polynomial-time algorithm which can be used to solve it.

Comment: @PeterKošinár Thank you. I probably didn't understand them right, then...I need clarification

Comment: @Calvin: Are you sure it's $\lfloor\frac{k_i+1}{2}\rfloor$? I don't think you can find an independent set of size $2$ in $K_3$, can you?

Comment: The main idea is that the graphs in which every vertex has degree 2 are very simple. So simple that one can actually find the size of their maximum independent set in polynomial time. Calvin hinted that such graphs are just composed of one or more disjoint cycles -- so it might be a good idea to look at what can we say about independent sets in a cycle (clearly, if the graph consists of more than one cycle, they can be treated... independently)

Comment: Thank you @PeterKošinár for the clarification

Comment: @CalvinLin but is finding a cycle in a graph is in P??

Comment: @user1067083 Not necessarily for any graph. BUT you are given a very special property of the graph, and we know what all the graphs must look like. As a related example, is it easy to find a cycle in the complete graph?

Comment: @Calvin Actually, no... Rahul has only rewritten your statement into an equivalent one :-)

Comment: @PeterKošinár Ah damn it, you're right. It's way too late to correct it now, but it should be $\lceil \frac{x-1}{2} \rceil $.

Comment: Guys, sorry to bother you further, please post a complete answer covering all what you said so I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few ingredients you might find useful for cooking the polynomial algorithm for 2-IS (no, it's not NP-complete; unless P=NP):

- Checking if every node in a graph has degree $2$ is easy.
- A graph in which every node has degree $2$ is a disjoint union of one or more cycles.
- The size of maximum independent set of a cycle on $n$ nodes is $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$.
- Finding all the cycles can be performed by a depth-first search, for example.